# Map Ctrl-Shift-V to an action in vi

Tags: windows, vim, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to be able to paste from the clipboard on gVim on Windows using Ctrl-Shift-V, just like in Terminator.

However, if I put this on my .vimrc

```
 imap <C-S-V> "+gP
```

The shortcut works without shift, meaning I can paste text with a simple Ctrl-V. This overrides the already existing capability, is there a way to paste only with Ctrl-Shift-V?

Comment: I don't think Windows supports multiple clipboards, it will be interesting to see responses to this.

Comment: I don't think Vim makes a difference between `<C-S-v>` and `<C-v>`.

Comment: Yes, you could do it with a more recent vim (at 
 least 8.1), see https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/23344/20313.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Vim cannot see the difference between `<C-V>`, `<C-v>`, and `<C-S-V>`.

If you want case sensitive mappings, you need to use unmodified characters, or the Alt key (e.g. `<A-v>` or `<M-v>` is different from `<A-V>` or `<M-V>`).

Answer (score 5):

Due to the way that the keyboard input is handled internally, this unfortunately isn't generally possible today, even in GVIM. Some key combinations, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + non-alphabetic cannot be mapped, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + letter vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + letter cannot be distinguished. (Unless your terminal sends a distinct *termcap* code for it, which most don't.) In insert or command-line mode, try typing the key combination. If nothing happens / is inserted, you cannot use that key combination. This also applies to `<Tab>` / `<C-I>`, `<CR>` / `<C-M>` / `<Esc>` / `<C-[>` etc. (Only exception is `<BS>` / `<C-H>`.) This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

Some people (foremost Paul LeoNerd Evans) want to fix that (even for console Vim in terminals that support this), and have floated various proposals, cp. http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/626e83fa4588b32a/bfbcb22f37a8a1f8

But as of today, no patches or volunteers have yet come forward, though many have expressed a desire to have this in a future Vim 8 major release.

Answer (score 1):

You can program the `Ctrl-Shift-v` to be intercepted by the terminal itself not vim, you can configure how that interception happens.

For me, I launch `Konsole` application, Click the Settings Menu -> Configure shortcuts -> Search for `Ctrl+Shift+v` and remap that to `Ctrl-V`.  So now this keyboard combination will not make it through to vim, and you can have Konsole do the right thing to paste the clipboard contents.

[image]

If you are using some terminal other than Konsole, you might search around for its functionality to intercept that keyboard combination and then hand-hold vim so it does the right thing.